# Is this community hidden by default?

Tags: support

I looked through my profile and I noticed that my activity for this stack exchange is set to "private", which means only I can see a full history of my activity on here. The community is marked as a "Hidden Community" on my SE profile.

I do not remember doing this. Was this done by default? Is this some sort of older bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know and can see this community is available for all to see

if you would like to check if it is hidden on your account you can do it in your profile settings

If you go you [account settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) you will see a section called *hide communities* under edit profile you will be given a list off all the SE' you are a part of and you will be able to hide or unhide them from there

Comment: It is still that way. I see nothing to indicate otherwise.